# Struggling with a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the MySQL query:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(no_intern, 1, 2 * 1),
  MAX(SUBSTRING(no_intern, (2 * 2) -1, 2))
  ) AS menu
FROM tb_m_menu
WHERE no_intern LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(no_intern, 1, 2 * level_menu), '%') FROM tb_m_menu WHERE id_menu = 1)
```

The result is: 0101

Now I want the result is always increased by one: 0101,0102,0103, but when I change the script like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(no_intern, 1, 2 * 1),
  MAX(SUBSTRING(no_intern, (2 * 2) -1, 2))+1 /*ditambahkan 1*/
  ) AS menu
FROM tb_m_menu
WHERE no_intern LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(no_intern, 1, 2 * level_menu), '%') FROM tb_m_menu WHERE id_menu = 1)
```

Result: 012,013

How to make this: 0102,0103,0104?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mislay **+1**
Try this one. I change the position of **+1** near **AS MENU**

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(no_intern, 1, 2 * 1),
MAX(SUBSTRING(no_intern, (2 * 2) -1, 2)))+1 AS menu
FROM tb_m_menu
WHERE no_intern LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(no_intern, 1, 2 * level_menu), '%') FROM tb_m_menu WHERE id_menu = 1)
```

Comment: did you solved your problem? @TaufiqurRohman? what is content of **no_intern**?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

I use this code:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(no_intern, 1, 2 * 1), 
  CONCAT(REPEAT('0', 2-LENGTH(MAX(SUBSTRING(no_intern, (2 * 2) -1, 2))+1)), MAX(SUBSTRING(no_intern, (2 * 2) -1, 2))+1)
  ) AS menu
FROM tb_m_menu 
WHERE no_intern LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(no_intern, 1, 2 * level_menu), '%') FROM tb_m_menu WHERE id_menu = 3)
```